# Trying to make an algorithim to conver infix to postfix but getting errors when calling push function

Tags: python

```
class Caculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def pop(self):
        return self.stack.pop()

    def push(self, item):
        return self.stack.append(item)

    def convert(self, infix):
        # use a stack to covert infix to postfix
        self.stack.clear()
        postfix = ''
        
        for c in infix:
            if c == '(':
                self.stack.push(c)
            elif c == ')':
                while self.stack.isEmpty() and self.stack.peek() != '(':
                    poped_char = self.stack.pop() and postfix.append(poped_char)
            elif c == '+' or c == '-':
                while self.stack.isEmpty() == False and self.stack.peek() == '/' or '*' or '+' or '-':
                    poped_char = self.stack.pop() and postfix.append(poped_char)
            elif c == '/' or c == '*':
                while self.stack.isEmpty() == False and self.stack.peek() == '/' or '*':
                    poped_char = self.stack.pop() and postfix.append(poped_char)
            else:
                self.stack.push(c)

            while self.stack.isEmpty() == False:
                poped_char = self.stack.pop() and postfix.append(poped_char)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ## instantiating the linked list
    cal = Caculator()

    input = input('Please enter a postfix')

    postfix = cal.convert(input)
    print(postfix)
```

I tried setting up specific functions for the push function but it still didn't work. This was also for a class so I can't use additional functions and can't use a dictionary to set priorities if that matters.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include entire error messages, including complete stack traces.

Comment: `self.stack` is just a plain old list here, so it doesn't have `.isEmpty()` or `.peek()` methods. It doesn't have `.push()` either, but `self.stack.push` is probably a typo for `self.push`.

Comment: It seems like you're expected to define a `Stack` class that has all these methods, not use a list directly.